# Open Android Studio Project into Android Studio from the command line

Tags: android, python, android-studio

I am trying to create a shortcut in Windows that will launch the latest version of Android Studio and load the given project in the shortcut.

I want to be able to create shortcuts for different project and click to open straight into the project.

If this can be done in a batch script or python script, that could work also.

Is this possible? It doesn't look like Android Studio takes command line arguments for opening a project.